# WebRTC iOS, how to mute video call

Tags: ios, webrtc, mute

I'm running demo Application of WebRTC on iOS.

But there is no sample for mute/unmute like older version of WebRTC.

I have search and found this

[How to disable audio in webrtc mobile app(ios) without changing in framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131447/how-to-disable-audio-in-webrtc-mobile-appios-without-changing-in-framework)

But newest source doesn't have **localStream**.
It added Audio track and video track.
If I set audio track "isEnable" to FALSE. then both 2 user can not hear anything.

Example User A and user B are in a call.
What I want is if user A mute, then only user B can not hear the voice.

Appreciate all help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by newest source? ARDAppClient should has the adding of local stream's Audio and Video Component.

Here is the working solution:

```
static NSString * const kARDAudioTrackId = @"ARDAMSa0";

//Initialization part
_factory = [[RTCPeerConnectionFactory alloc] init];
RTCAudioTrack *_localAudioTrack = [_factory audioTrackWithSource:source
                                            trackId:kARDAudioTrackId];

//For mute and unmute the local stream Audio
- (void)toggleAudioMute {
    self.audioMute = !self.audioMute;
    _localAudioTrack.isEnabled = !self.audioMute;
}
```

Comment: It work well. The problem here is set _localAudioTrack as a static variable. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In IOS 12 this way brokes peerConnection

Comment: This still shows the orange microphone indicator (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76388730/how-to-mute-microphone-and-remove-orange-microphone-indicator-with-webrtc-in-ios). Do you have any insight on how to fix this?